# Typing `this.dataset` i get undefined

Tags: javascript

I want to know why i get undefined when i type the code bellow?

```js
console.log(this.dataset)
```

```html
<h1 data-item="7">Hello JS!</h1>
```

I ask this because i expect to get `data-item="7"`.

Comment: You need to supply the surrounding context (code block) which will tell us how and what `this` may be bound to.

Comment: How would JavaScript be able to know what is `this`?

Comment: @Jax-p, this is not = with window object in my case ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but you have to select some element first. Something like `document.querySelector("h1").dataset`.  `this` usually references to function. Only in jQuery is `$(this)` used for elements in listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not just refer to **this** like that. you should specify that you need *dataset* of a specific element

Look snippet below:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('#t').dataset);
```

```html
<h1 id="t" data-item="7">Hello JS!</h1>
```